# Sitemap file entries for blog and main php site

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap

I'm creating a sitemap manually.

It's a PHP site with a WordPress blog.

Here's the main site: http://wordfruit.com

And here's the blog: http://blog.wordfruit.com

1. Can I put the blog URL in the same Sitemap file as the main site urls?
2. And can I just place the feedburner URL in the Sitemap instead of all the blog urls? -- this URL: http://feeds.feedburner.com/wordfruit
3. And if I place the feedburner url in the Sitemap file, will all new blog posts be taken care of without making any changes to the Sitemap?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. [No](http://www.google.com/support/feedburner/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97090).

> Using FeedBurner with Google Webmaster Tools If you use Google
>
> Webmaster Tools and expect to submit a feed as the source for a
>   sitemap of your blog or website, you should use your site's original
>   feed, and not your FeedBurner feed, for the sitemap to work properly.
>   Here's why:
>
> If you use our feed stats services to track feed item click throughs,
>   FeedBurner rewrites your item URLs so that we can track the clicks
>   before sending subscribers back to your website to view the original
>   content. These links use the feedburner.com domain, of course.
>   Sitemaps expect the original domain of the website in question to be
>   found in the feed in order to function properly; these
>   feedburner.com-rewritten permalinks will not work and then cause
>   Webmaster Tools to report a sitemaps error. This error can be
>   completely sidestepped by providing your original source feed instead.
>   Webmaster Tools won't lack for any information or functionality as a
>   result, and you can keep click through tracking turned on in your
>   FeedBurner feed.
>
> One other point: if you have a site whose original feed redirects
>   traffic to FeedBurner (for example, if you use Blogger redirection, or
>   you use our FeedSmith plugin for WordPress), you will need to give
>   Webmaster Tools the address of a feed that does not get redirected as
>   a sitemap source.
>
> For Blogger users, the following general feed URL format should always
>   work:
>
> `http://mybloggerblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?redirect=false`
>
> For WordPress FeedSmith plugin users, use this URL format:
>
> `http://www.mywpblog.com/?feed=rss2`
>
> For all other platforms, other feed URL variations that are not
>   redirected are what you need to provide.

- A moot point since you shouldn't use feedburner feeds for sitemaps.

Comment: thanks John -- so does that mean that I need to 1. add the plugin FeedSmith in my WordPress; 2. add the url http://www.blog.wordfruit.com/?feed=rss2 to the same Sitemap files that contain all the pages at http://wordfruit.com and 3. once I've done that, does that mean that all new blog posts will be taken care of without the need to make changes to the Sitemap file?

Comment: 1. I'm not a Wordpress guru but I would say using that plug-in would do what you need. 2. I think that is correct. If not you can create a master sitemap file and then link to your site's sitemap and the blogs sitemap. The xmlsitemaps.org website explains how to do that. 3. Yes.